# Invalid utf8 character string + LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE+ MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando importar um arquivo de estoque em CSV e neste arquivos contem diversos acentos  À Á Ú ' ñ  etc nos campos Descricao , NomeFornecedor. Banco e e os campos estão UTF8 na instancia de conexão também. so que quando importo o arquivo informar que General error: 1300 Invalid utf8 character string: 'CAPA PL
que é CAPA PLÁSTICA
Segue o codigo abaixo ele esta correto pois uso em uma outra importação sem acentuação. Ja tentei com utf8mb4. Alguem pode me ajudar?

```
 $import = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE estoque_sap CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' IGNORE 1 LINES ( Material, Descricao, @Estoque, Deposito, TipoDeposito, Posicao, HU, Tipo, Fornecedor, NomeFornecedor, @DataEntrada, Centro) SET Estoque = REPLACE( REPLACE( @Estoque, '.' ,'' ), ',', '.' ), DataEntrada = STR_TO_DATE(@DataEntrada, '%Y-%m-%d')";  
            $stmt = $PDO->prepare($import);
            $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ja consegui so coloquei CHARACTER SET Latin1